# How can I compile GNU Triangulated Surface Library GTS in windows for Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gnu, pixelsense, triangulation, triangular

How can I install/build/compile GNU Triangulated Surface Library GTS using visual studio 2010 c++ under windows platform. I want to use gts library in my visual studio c++ project.
I tried a lot but no success. I couldn't even find the instruction for installation in windows. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Under src folder, there is a makefile.msc.
You can try.